# What makes a Servo Skull fly?

Tags: warhammer-40k, rogue-trader, dark-heresy-1e

I was having a discussion about how many attachments a single servo skull could carry, and the topic led onto how a Servo Skull actually stayed afloat.

One theory was that it used a jet-based mechanism, this restricting the amount if add-ons it could carry, depending on the weight of the attachments.

The other theory was at it used a form of anti-grav technology (however minor), thus greatly increasing the total carry weight of it's attachments, considering it was currently defying gravity.

So how does a Servo Skull actually stay in the air?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Rogue Trader* rulebook would like to have a word with you (page 375):

> Servo-skulls are human skulls (often that of a favoured servant or low ranking tech-priest) that have been fitted with rudimentary artificial intelligence, support systems, and **an anti-grav motor** to provide mobility.

For carrying capacity use the standard rules from page 267 with the ST and T provided in servo skull's stat block.